# django 4.1 polls tutorial, all done Admin working fine but index not found

Tags: python, django

ok polls tutorial is done and can enter questions, vote, etc.  but from the admin pages View site aka localhost:8000 gives...

```
    Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

dose/
admin/
The empty path didn’t match any of these.
```

Now I have polls/views.py...

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views import generic

from .models import Choice, Question


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Return the last five published questions (not including those set to be
        published in the future).
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

and mysite/urls.py set to ...

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and polls/urls.py set to...

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

The only hint I can find is that all the imports show error highlights in VSCode with the Error "reportMissingModuleSources"

But python and django run perfectly well everywhere but index.html

Answer (score 1):

No url at `http://localhost:8000/` address is expected behaviour, where you want to go is `http://localhost:8000/polls/`.

If you want go directly to the desired View without writing `polls/` prefix you should define your urls this way:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

So you place `path()` call without url prefix. Generally if you `include` any url group you define the beginning of address this way.

Comment: Thanks,  but as I showed in my question, mysite/urls.py and polls/urls.py are exactly as defined in the 4.1 Tutorial.  The Admin page has in its header http://localhost:8000/  not http://localhost:8000/polls/  In your answer ' ' does not define a view to use i.e. views.IndexView

Comment: Another reason is that in the Admin header of the Polls tutorial there is a link to "VIEW SITE" that goes to http://localhost:8000 and I don't see where to change that to http://localhost:8000/polls/